# Gitlab fails to start on a new install

Tags: gitlab, unicorn, centos6

I recently did a fresh install of Gitlab on a Centos 6.7 server but it will not start and I am having a hard time figuring out why. I get the following when starting.

```
[root@server1 gitlab]# service gitlab start
Starting unicorn: master failed to start, check stderr log for details
                                                           [FAILED]
Starting sidekiq:
```

I checked the logs in /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log but nothing has been written since I did the install and I see no errors in the logs.

Running 'sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production' gives me the following

```
System information
System:     CentOS 6.7
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.1.2p95
Gem Version:    2.2.2
Bundler Version:1.10.6
Rake Version:   10.4.2
Sidekiq Version:4.0.1

GitLab information
Version:    8.3.0.pre
Revision:   e8d35ea
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: postgresql
URL:        http://git.mydomain.com
HTTP Clone URL: http://git.mydomain.com/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@git.mydomain.com:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    2.6.8
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

running 'sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production' gives me the following. I assume Gitlab shell fails to start becuase gitlab fails to start.

```
Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 2.6.8 ? ... OK (2.6.8)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
hooks directories in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 500
gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u git -H editor /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking Reply by email ...

Reply by email is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking Reply by email ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Git configured with autocrlf=input? ... yes
Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Uploads directory setup correctly? ... skipped (no tmp uploads folder yet)
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  Redownload the init script
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
projects have namespace: ... can't check, you have no projects
Redis version >= 2.4.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.1.0 ? ... yes (2.1.2)
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.12)
Active users: 1

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

**What can I do to debug and potentially fix this issue? How do I know what is causing the problem?**

Comment: I was looking at the wrong log, there was another one at /home/git/gitlab/log/ which I did not see intially

Comment: Did you find your problem in that log?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the exact error but I got everything working. I believe the issue I was having was that another instance of unicorn was already listening on that port.